# how to use Java PushbackInputStream to read a number

Tags: java

I need to read off a number (could be integer, double, positive, negative, etc.) from `PushbackInputStream`. Does I have to read byte by byte and testing whether they are between `0-9` and also testing the delimiting space?

Or how to read the rest in the stream into a String array using spaces as separation?

**Edit**

Let me make myself a bit more clear. I want to do some parsing of expressions involving operators and numbers. I probably (what is your good way if not?) need to use `PushbackInputStream` whenever I encounter the part of a number instead an operator, since in this case I will unread/pushback the part for the number I just mistakenly read. For example, I want to parse "10+20*30", I read `1`, which is not in the `enum` of my operators, I put it back, try to read a number off the `PushbackInputStream`. So how to do it here?

Comment: There are so many easier ways to do it. I've never seen the need for that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Scanner class for that purpose.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Use this code to read a single integer from a PushbackInputStream called *psi*:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(_psi_);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

The Scanner also has methods to read other data types. If you want to read an (small) unknown number of int's from a text file, you could use something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(_psi_);
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(sc.hasNextInt())
  ints.add(sc.nextInt());

Integer[] theIntArray = ints.toArray(new Integer[]);
```

EDIT: As an alternative you could read individual characters (I'd use InputStreamReader for that) and check whether you've got a part of a number or not. If it is a part of a number, append the current char to the end of a String (*). When you see an operator, parse the String at once with Integer.parseInt() for example.

(*) Building a String by appending individual characters is bad practice, since it's very slow. Using a StringBuilder is usually the better option.

Comment: The thing is: I am not sure how to get back to PushbackInputStream after converting it to Scanner? For example, I want to read/parse `-45.3*27-24`, here I need to read off `-45.3` first. Then read off `*`, possibly `2`, but I put back/unread it into the stream. Then I need to read off `27`, etc...

Comment: @littleEinstein Sorry but I don't get what you are planning to do exactly, when are you pushing back and when you are not and why :) You wrote you read push back `*` and `2`? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I am trying to do some parsing. I need to read char by char in order to know the operators, but I also like to read a number as a whole for convenience. Maybe I should read the bytes and store them in an byte[], and then use the array to fill a String, then use Integer.valueOf etc. to get the number.

Comment: Have a look at the next() methods of the Scanner class. It allows you to read any tokens. next() just returns the next token as a string. You can specify the delimiter between tokens by passing a regular expression to scanner.useDelemiter("regular expression goes here").

I would refrain from trying to switch between Scanner and the InputStream. Just do all your reading with Scanner.

Comment: If I use scanner.useDelimiter with multiple delimiters, how can I know what current delimiter is? Is there something like `StringTokenizer(arg1, arg2, true);` the third `true` argument in Scanner class? Maybe I should use StringTokenizer instead of Scanner?

Comment: Yes, StringTokenizer is another excellent alternative. With that you'll have to pass the numbers to Integer.parseInt(...) obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the `PushbackInputStream` like this:

```java
byte buf[]; // some buffer
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
PushbackInputStream f = new PushbackInputStream(in);
int c;
while ((c = f.read()) != -1) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    int d = f.read();
    if (matchesSomeCondition(d)) {
        doSomethingInteresting(c, d);
    } else {
        f.unread(d);
    }
    }
}
```

The interesting thing about the `PushbackInputStream` is, that you can peek into the stream for as many bytes as you like to look for patterns. If the patterns don't match, you push the bytes pack into it using the `unread` method.

Comment: doesn't `int d = f.read();` only read a byte, that is, a single digit number?

Comment: Yes, it does, but then you read one more with `d = f.read()`, this can be an delimiter like space for example. I just wanted you to show the principle, because I don't know what you want to do exactly (you state  different number types)... When you *want* to use Pushback then thats how it works.

Comment: I of course know how pushback works. But I also want to combine this functionality to read a number at once, if possible. Or at least, some short/nice code to do that.

Comment: please see my comment to Simon's answer for what I want to do exactly.